# Eliminate several Nan using Pandas Pivot from list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

My python list is:

```
prop = [('City', ' Python Town'),
 ('Property Type', ' Townhouse'),
 ('Square Feet', ' 1400'),
 ('Zip Code', ' 5000'),
 ('Bathrooms', ' 3'),
 ('Bedrooms', ' 3'),
 ('MLS', ' 0202'),
 ('Price1', ' 1295000'),
 ('Posted On', ' Dec 1, 2019')]
```

If I index it, an example would be :

```
prop[0][0] = City
prop[0][1] = Python Town
```

Converted to dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(prop)
df.pivot(columns = 0, values = 1)
```

Get this:

```
    Bathrooms   Bedrooms    City         MLS    Posted On   Price1  Property Type   Square Feet Zip Code
0   NaN         NaN         Python Town NaN     NaN         NaN     NaN             NaN         NaN
1   NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN     Townhouse       NaN         NaN
2   NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN     NaN             1485        NaN
3   NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN     NaN             NaN         5000
4   3           NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN     NaN             NaN         NaN
5   NaN           3         NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN     NaN             NaN         NaN
6   NaN         NaN         NaN         0202    NaN         NaN     NaN             NaN         NaN
7   NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN         1295000 NaN             NaN         NaN
8   NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN     Dec 10, 2019NaN     NaN             NaN         NaN
```

How to I eliminate the row index and make it 1 row while eliminated all the unnecessary Nan's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the pivot, You could transform it, to get the output like this:

```
df.T
```

```
              0              1            2         3          4         5      6         7             8
0          City  Property Type  Square Feet  Zip Code  Bathrooms  Bedrooms    MLS    Price1     Posted On
1   Python Town      Townhouse         1400      5000          3         3   0202   1295000   Dec 1, 2019
```

You can also make those column headers with this:

```
df1 = df.T
new_columns = df1.T[:][0]
df1 = df1[1:]
df1.columns = new_columns
df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)
df1 = df1.rename_axis(columns=None)
```

```
           City Property Type Square Feet Zip Code Bathrooms Bedrooms    MLS    Price1     Posted On
0   Python Town     Townhouse        1400     5000         3        3   0202   1295000   Dec 1, 2019
```

depending on how you want it formatted.

Comment: So my prop list above is actually 500 lists.  And its dynamic.  The one in my example has 9 items in a list of list.  Some have 12 items, some 5.  Thoughts on how I can add multiple lists of dynamic lists to that dataframe?  Would it be best to make them a dictionary with k,v pairs and insert?  I may post another question about how to do that but thought I'd try here first.

Comment: @MarkM I'm used to csv. I would look at how pandas formats then Take df1, use df1.to_csv(), df1.to_dict, df1.to_numpy and pick ones that suites your programming needs better

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use pivot for something this small. You can just transpose either before or after making the dataFrame

```
>> import numpy as np
>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.transpose(prop))
>> print(df)

              0              1            2  ...      6         7             8
0          City  Property Type  Square Feet  ...    MLS    Price1     Posted On
1   Python Town      Townhouse         1400  ...   0202   1295000   Dec 1, 2019
```

If you want the first row as the index:

```
>> df.columns = df.loc[0]
>> df.drop(0, axis=0, inplace=True)
>> df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
>> print(df)


           City  Property Type  ...   Price1        Posted On
0   Python Town      Townhouse  ...   1295000      Dec 1, 2019
```